# Set PPTP Passthrough in Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, vpn, pptp

I have a big problem with VPN PPTP connections in Mac OS X SL and the problem exists in all my computers that I work with. When I connect to a PPTP connection, the connection is good for about two or three minutes but after that the line drops without strict disconnecting. I read in a forum that I must change the passthrough option for PPTP. But I don't know where to change it. Would you please guiding me about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever thing said that means that you should set that option on your home router/wifi. Or you can ask whoever set that thing up for you.